# mockito: can not mock a class with a custom classloaader

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, classloader

[EDITED]

Seems a regression in new releases https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2304#issuecomment-847561882

[END EDIT]

When calling mockito from a class that was instantiated in a different context, it throws a casting exception. Though, it was possible to do in mockito 1.x but upgrading to 3.x it fails.

Here the error I get:

```
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
ClassCastException occurred while creating the mockito mock :
  class to mock : '...MyTest.MyClass.MyOtherClass', loaded by classloader : 'java.net.URLClassLoader@e73f9ac'
  created class : 'org.mockito.codegen.MyOtherClass$MockitoMock$1564550697', loaded by classloader : 'net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.MultipleParentClassLoader@75d4a5c2'
  proxy instance class : 'org.mockito.codegen.MyOtherClass$MockitoMock$1564550697', loaded by classloader : 'net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.MultipleParentClassLoader@75d4a5c2'
  instance creation by : ObjenesisInstantiator

You might experience classloading issues, please ask the mockito mailing-list.

    at ....MyTest$MyClass.initialize(MyTest.java:23)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mockito.codegen.MyOtherClass$MockitoMock$1564550697 cannot be cast to org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockAccess
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(SubclassByteBuddyMockMaker.java:49)
```

This is my code:

```
public class MyTest {

public static class MyClass {
    public static class MyOtherClass {
        
    }
    
    public void initialize() {
        MyOtherClass mayOtherMock = Mockito.mock(MyOtherClass.class); // THROWS EXCEPTION
    }
}

@Test
public void myTest() throws Exception {
    URLClassLoader customLoader = new URLClassLoader(getClasspathURLs(), null);
    
    Class<?> clz = customLoader.loadClass(MyClass.class.getName());
    Method mtd = clz.getMethod("initialize");
    
    Object inst = clz.newInstance();
    
    mtd.invoke(inst, new Object[0]); // HERE TEST FAILS
}

private URL[] getClasspathURLs() throws Exception {
    return Arrays.stream(
            System.getProperty("java.class.path").split(File.pathSeparator))
            .map(s -> {
                try {
                    return new File(s).toURI().toURL();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new URL[0]);
}
```

}

Comment: Are you executing into a JEE container? Why do you need to mock a class loaded from another context? Is there a copy of Mockito libraries on each context?

Comment: This is just for testing, we need to assure that certain code works different depending on certain stuff present in the classpath, hence we need to modify the classloader with different configurations to test our code

Comment: Did you notice the sentence “*You might experience classloading issues, please ask the mockito mailing-list.*” in the exception message? Besides that, instead of `mtd.invoke(inst, new Object[0])` you can simply write `mtd.invoke(inst)` and instead of `.collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new URL[0])` you can simply write `toArray(URL[]::new)`

Comment: Opened an issue: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2304#issuecomment-847561882 seems a regression in the lib.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Mockito issue but JVM's.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3

> At run time, a class or interface is determined not by its name alone, but by a pair: its binary name (§4.2.1) and its defining class loader. Each such class or interface belongs to a single run-time package. The run-time package of a class or interface is determined by the package name and defining class loader of the class or interface.

The identity of a class is composed of package, className and classLoaderName. So if you load same class twice with different classloaders then instances are not identical and attempt to cast one to another fails with ClassCastException

Comment: While this is true, the OP states: "_Though, it was possible to do in mockito 1.x but upgrading to 3.x it fails_". That would suggest it actually is a Mockito issue, or at least an issue with how the OP is using the newer version. Assuming what they were doing then versus now is truly equivalent.

Comment: Not in this case since you can use different classloaders in the same JVM. In fact the problem is not present in previous mockito releases. I guess the problem is how it creates classes ignoring the classloader on which the class calling mockito was created, or not configuring correctly the context.